# Alinear bitmap image a center

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo el siguiente código para generar un `bitmap` en un ticket para una impresora térmica:

```
String ticketPreSelectedImage = SharedPref.getInstance(this).getTicketPreSelectedImagePath();

if (ticketPreSelectedImage != null) {

    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ticketPreSelectedImage);

    ticketBuilder.addCommand(new byte[]{27, 97, 1, 0}); // Esta linea es la que creo que centra la imagen

    ticketBuilder.addImage(image, image.getWidth() * 1, image.getHeight() * 1);
}
```

Este código lo que hace es alinearme la imagen en el ticket a la izquierda y no se muy bien como centrarla para que quede bien,

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La línea que marcas lo que hace es enviar un código [ESC/POS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESC/P). Concretamente, se puede traducir a lo siguiente:

```
ESC a 1 0
```

Revisando la [lista de comandos ESC/POS](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=72), encontramos lo siguiente para [`ESC a`](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=58):

> [Formato]
>
> `ESC a n`
>
> En el modo Standard, alinea todos los datos en una lines al layout seleccionado, usando n de la siguiente manera:
>
> ```
>   n          Justificado
> -----------------------------------
> 0, 48 Justificado a la izquierda
> 1, 49 Centrado
> 2, 50 Justificado a la derecha
> ```

Tomando eso en cuenta, tu código está enviando un 0 después del 1 que es lo que quieres (centrado). Así que deberías tener lo siguiente en tu código:

```
ticketBuilder.addCommand(new byte[]{27, 97, 1}); //27=ESC 97=a 1=Centrado
```

---

<sub>P.D. No se que librería estás usando para enviar los comandos, y es posible que necesite enviar un 0 para marcar el final del comando, pero añado mi respuesta ya que creo que la información sobre ESC/P y el comando que estás usando puede resultarte útil</sub>

Comment: Buenas, muchas gracias por responder, he probado lo que me has comentado y sigue imprimiendome la imagen alineada a la izquierda, mirare información del comando addCommand porque tengo dudas si sobre una imagen funciona, sobre una linea si que funciona pero a la hora de aplicarlo a un bitmap no estoy tan seguro,

Comment: @J.Burrueco si efectivamente, ese comando únicamente afecta al texto en casi todas las impresoras (en algunas podría afectar al bitmap tambien). Para centrar la imagen, me temo que tendrás que hacerlo de forma manual.

Comment: @J.Burrueco mira [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49818789/579895) a ver si te da una pista. Básicamente, recomienda que añadas un espacio en blanco a la izquierda de tu bitmap antes de pasarselo a la impresora...Concretamente [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44060669)  parece prometedora..

Comment: Por último @J.Burrueco...sería interesante saber que librería estas usando para imprimir, tal vez tenga alguna opción que te permita centrar la imagen

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por responder, por lo que veo debo pasarle un padding guardado en un int con la anchura de la imagen, mi ultima pregunta es, como declaro el padding? interpreta un numero como un conjunto de espacios? o como guardo en una variable int un numero de espacios?

Comment: La libreria no estoy muy seguro si es esto pero es bitmapFactory,

Comment: Perdon la libreria es Sam4sbuilder, un saludo